# How to give Google storage bucket permission to Google Speech to text API?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I have created Google Storage bucket to perform Google Speech-to-text for the audio file in the bucket. But this is not working as the bucket is denying access to the Google Speech API.

Error Message:
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access PERMISSION_DENIED

Speech uses API key for authentication and Storage uses service account key for authentication. I have already given access to the service account in bucket permission.

Is it possible to give Speech access to storage bucket?

I also tried giving bucket permission to service account. But it does not work.

Comment: Where are you calling the API from? Are you calling it from a resource within Google Cloud?

Comment: I am calling the API from my local machine. As @asbovelw mentioned, I was missing the access token for authorization in Speech API request header. After adding the service account's access token I was able to access the bucket.
curl -X POST \
  https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
  -d '{ '\''audio'\'': { '\''uri'\'':<storage_uri>' }, '\''config'\'': { '\''languageCode'\'': '\''en-US'\'' } }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using authentication at all;
this is shown by "Anonymous caller" in the error message.

It seems you are directly accessing the API, either with `curl` or another tool.

In order to authenticate this way, you can follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi).
Look at the `curl` examples but do it like this (using `gcloud auth print-access-token` as an easy way to generate the access token from the CLI), substituting "$BUCKET_NAME" with your bucket's name and "$OBJECT_NAME" with your object's name (with environment variables or literally):

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/$BUCKET_NAME/o/$OBJECT_NAME?alt=media"`

Be careful, though, as this downloads the file to your terminal and can mess with its display. To avoid this, just append a "> $OBJECT_NAME" to the command to save the requested file.